# Passing structure to a function

Tags: c++, function, structure

I was practicing different methods to assign values to the structure variables. But, when 
I tried this I am getting some garbage value. Here is the code.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std ;

struct Distance{
    int feet ;
    int inches;
};

void get_val(Distance );               
void disp(Distance);

int main(){

    Distance l, m ;                   //Objects 
    get_val(l);
    get_val(m);
    disp(l);
    disp(m);
    return 0  ;
}

void get_val(Distance length){
    cout<<"\nEnter Length "
        <<"\nFeet  : ";
    cin>>length.feet;
    cout<<"\nInches : ";
    cin>>length.inches;
}
void disp(Distance length){
    cout<<"\nLength : \n"
        <<"Feet : "<<length.feet
        <<"\nInches : "<<length.inches ;
}
```

Why am I getting garbage value as the Output ?

Comment: Which output returns garbage? The `l` and `m` are not initialized!

Comment: inside the disp() function

Comment: Pass your structure instances by reference: `void get_val(Distance& );`

Comment: Why are you not checking `cin >> length.feet` is successful?

Comment: can somebody please explain the reason. thanks :)

Comment: @prodicus I did. You're just modifying a copy of that object with that function now.

Answer (score 9):

pass them by reference.

```
void get_val(Distance&);


void get_val(Distance &length){}
```

You change value of structure created in main function in another function so you have to pass them by reference or use pointers.

### Edited:

Thanks to  Benjamin Lindley .

Comment: The `get_val` function should take them by reference. The `disp` function should take them either by value, or by const reference.

Answer (score 9):

The comments so far tell you what to do, but don't seem to go into the reasons why you need to do that.

In C++ (as well as C) when you pass data to a function, it makes a copy of that data which is local to that function- it's not the original data! Not to mention it takes up memory and adds a little more time to the execution time (although it won't matter until you get into larger structures).

So the solution is to instead pass the memory location of the data- a reference to it. The reference is "copied" in that it just takes the location (probably a `size_t` or something that could represent the position in memory) and copies that, but uses that location to "reference" the actual data. It removes a bit of the overhead in copying *and* allows you to modify the original data.

In C you would use a pointer instead of a reference, in C++ it's generally favorable to use a reference (because it means the thing you pass is already initialized and not going to segfault). You've probably seen the syntax and already used it, but I'm copying it here for redundancy:

```
void get_val(Distance&);
void disp(const Distance&);
//...


void get_val(Distance& length){
    cout<<"\nEnter Length "
        <<"\nFeet  : ";
    cin>>length.feet;
    cout<<"\nInches : ";
    cin>>length.inches;
}

void disp(const Distance& length){
    cout<<"\nLength : \n"
        <<"Feet : "<<length.feet
        <<"\nInches : "<<length.inches ;
}
```

You use a reference just like a regular variable (and just as a hint, variables are a type of reference themselves! You call the function the same way- `get_val(l);` and `disp(l);`.) A `const` reference is just a reference you can't change. Usually you'll use them for functions that simply read the value and don't do anything else.

Comment: The way you are describing references sounds like the way they may be implemented. But note that formally, a reference is an alias for an object. This object may even be an rvalue, so the "address-of" analogy breaks down. The compiler may be able to perform different sets of optimizations for references and pointers.

Comment: I have come to the conclusion that it is counter-productive to think of references in terms of pointers. The most clever sentence about references I have ever read (I don't recall where) was "A reference *is* the object." I think if you understand this sentence, then you understand references.

Comment: @juanchopanza You're correct, it definitely isn't only the memory location. I just chose that explanation because it made the most sense to me when I was learning, but it isn't applicable everywhere. I won't edit my response, though, in order to give some context to your explanation and keep it consistent.

Answer (score 5):

You need to pass a `Distance` to `get_val` by reference. Then signature of `get_val` needs to be

```
void get_val(Distance& length);
```

With your implementation, there are two problems:

1. You are modifying a local copy of `Distance` in `get_val`.
2. You haven't initialized `l` or `m`.

Answer (score 5):

Use pass by reference (with the use of const)
i.e.

```
void get_val(Distance &length)
void disp(const Distance &length){
```

Comment: Why have you used const inside disp() ? Can't I just do void disp(Distance length) ?

Comment: Yes - But using const in this case is better.

Comment: @prodicus It's good style to pass a const reference. Passing by value creates an extra copy, and using a plain reference doesn't indicate the function doesn't change the object.

Answer (score 3):

You should pass the object of structure by reference.  Use:

```
get_val (Distance& l);
```

In your case object is being passed by value. Hence when you call the function `get_val (Distance l)`, the value gets stored in `l`'s member variables but when the control returns back to the main, the values you stored are not reflected because they were stored in a "copy" of object and not actual object.

There are some advantages of using reference but one that definitely stands out is that it prevents creating a new copy of object and reduces the overhead of calling the copy constructor and reduces memory footprint. Second being you can modify original object.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass it that way you're just passing a copy of `Distance`. So the `Distance` object inside `get_val` is merely a copy of `l` and `m` and neither `l` nor `m` gets updated.

What you want to do instead is pass pointers to `l` and `m`:

```
void get_val(Distance *length) {
    cout<<"\nEnter Length "
        <<"\nFeet  : ";
    cin>>length->feet;
    cout<<"\nInches : ";
    cin>>length->inches;
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
get_val(&l);
get_val(&m);
```

Either that or write the function to pass by reference (see R Sahu's answer).

Comment: Either will work. The thing to realize is that C++ is strictly pass by value. It will always copy what is passed into a function. So you must pass it a pointer or reference which will be copied into the function but point to the same object. Besides, the last time I used C++ references didn't exist so I can't say I know the syntax.

Comment: You were doing C++ prior to 1983?

Comment: OK. I just read a bit more about pass by reference (I've never used it because when I was programming C++ it wasn't available) and it appears that C++ does support pass by reference semantics if you declare the argument as a reference.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: 1999. My compiler didn't have it or I just wasn't aware of it. All I learned in College was pointers and references was for Java.

Comment: Except that Java is pass by value. Passing a java "reference" is semantically closer to passing a C++ pointer than a C++ reference.

Comment: Passing `Distance` via a pointer is bad programming style here. Java uses the word "reference" with a different meaning. For the most part, a Java reference is a C++ pointer without pointer arithmetics. Other than that, it shares all its problems, e.g. the possibility of the "reference" being `null` when you do not need that feature (often resulting in the strangely correctly named `NullPointerException`). Java does not have anything like C++ references.